# How do I manually set the resolution of an external monitor on my laptop?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, resolution

I have a second monitor that I'd like to use with my laptop but it doesn't report its full resolution to Ubuntu and I'm stuck using it in 1024x800 mode. Yuck.

I'd like to manually set the resolution somehow but I'm worried about messing with Xorg.conf since that monitor isn't always plugged in.

edit: I can use the screen, just at the wrong resolution

Answer (score 2):

I was able to manually add the required modes using the following commands

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.00
```

Although others may have to adjust the resolution, refresh rate and other values on their own

Answer (score 0):

Click the little icon on the top right corner.  It will show a pull-down menu.  Select Displays, you should see a box showing both your laptop screen and external screen.  Click the external screen, then you can select resolution, rotation, etc.  I'm using an external screen with on the laptop right now.

Comment: I can use the screen, it's just not at the right resolution

Comment: can you adjust the resolution using the method I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, but I still the only options are 800x600 and 1024x768. The correct resolution is 1280x960